# Subversion is very slow in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Subversion is very slow in IDEA 10.5, It always refresh Subversion history after update java source or commit, every refresh Subversion history about cost 30 seconds，but in Eclipse,Subversion is very fast

Comment: This issue exists even today. I'm running `IDEA 15.04/JDK 7 (64-bit)/Windows 7`. Any help is appreciated. SVN update or compare with repository options are very slow in `Version Control` plugin in IDEA compared to Eclipse on the same machine.

Comment: this is still issue, probably wrong implementation by JetBrains... larger commits are better of being made with tortoise or other clients

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you running? I've seen some problems with 64 bit only Linux kernels and jsvn earlier.

Answer (score -3):

There can be multiple reason,

1. Subversion repository connectivity can be very slow or may have huge network traffic.
2. It can be also caused by insufficient performance of your computer.

As far as I know there know intelij Idea 10.5 related issues with subversion. Any way try 11.0.1 it is more stable and more features compared to 10.5

Regards
Isuru